# ValueError: Only support at least one signature key. while converting model into TFlite image

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

I have model and it is capable of detecting the human moment through heatmap samples and I'm trying to convert the model into tflite image I'm getting ***ValueError: Only support at least one signature key.***

```
  File "D:\ppl_count.tar (1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\Human_activity.py", line 360, in <module>
tm.run(LRCN_model)
File "D:\ppl_count.tar (1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\Human_activity.py", line 136, in run
self.create_tflite_image()
  File "D:\ppl_count.tar (1)\ppl_count\ppl_count\Human_activity.py", line 126, in create_tflite_image
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(self.tf_model_dir)  # path to the SavedModel directory
File "C:\Users\L99002507\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 1778, in from_saved_model
raise ValueError("Only support at least one signature key.")
ValueError: Only support at least one signature key.
```

And my code:

```
class TrainModel:
 def __init__(self):
    # The Tensorflow model and properties file will be stored here
    self.tf_model_dir = os.path.join(basedir, 'models', 'ir', 'tensorflow')
    os.makedirs(self.tf_model_dir, exist_ok=True)
    self.tf_model_file = os.path.join(self.tf_model_dir, 'ir.pb')

    self.tf_properties_file = os.path.join(self.tf_model_dir, 'ir.json')
    self.tf_tflite_file = os.path.join(self.tf_model_dir, 'ir.tflite')

    h5_model_dir = os.path.join(basedir, 'models', 'ir', 'keras')
    os.makedirs(h5_model_dir, exist_ok=True)
    self.h5_model_file = os.path.join(h5_model_dir, 'ir.h5')
    self.h5_weights_file = os.path.join(h5_model_dir, 'ir.json')

    # Base directory that contains your training images and dataset files
    self.dataset_base_dir = os.path.join(basedir, 'datasets', 'ir')
    self.dataset_dir = os.path.join(self.dataset_base_dir, 'dataset')

    # Store your thermal camera images here
    self.img_dir = os.path.join(self.dataset_base_dir, 'images')

    # Size of the input images
    self.input_size = (8, 8)

    self.classes = CLASSES_LIST
    self.predictions = ''

 def save_model_tf2(self, model):
    from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import 
   convert_variables_to_constants_v2

    # Save model to SavedModel format
    os.makedirs(self.tf_model_dir, exist_ok=True)
    tf.saved_model.save(model, self.tf_model_dir)

    # Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
    full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
    full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
        x=tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

    # Get frozen ConcreteFunction
    frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
    frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()

    layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]
    # print("-" * 50)
    # print("Frozen model layers: ")
    # for layer in layers:
    #     print(layer)

    # print("-" * 50)
    # print("Frozen model inputs: ")
    # print(frozen_func.inputs)
    # print("Frozen model outputs: ")
    # print(frozen_func.outputs)

    # Save frozen graph from frozen ConcreteFunction to hard drive
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                      logdir=os.path.dirname(self.tf_model_file),
                      name=os.path.basename(self.tf_model_file),
                      as_text=False)

    properties = {}
    classes = self.classes
    if isinstance(self.classes, np.ndarray):
        classes = self.classes.tolist()

    properties['classes'] = classes
    properties['input_size'] = [*self.input_size]
    print(f'properties{properties}')
    with open(self.tf_properties_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(properties, f)

def create_tflite_image(self):
    # Convert the model
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(self.tf_model_dir)  # path to the SavedModel directory
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save the model.
    with open(self.tf_tflite_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

def run(self, model):
    self.save_model_tf2(model)

    self.create_tflite_image()
def create_LRCN_model():
"""
This function will construct the required LRCN model.
Returns:
    model: It is the required constructed LRCN model.
"""

# We will use a Sequential model for model construction.
model = Sequential()

# Define the Model Architecture.
# #######################################################################################################################

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
                          input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(32))

model.add(Dense(len(CLASSES_LIST), activation='softmax'))

# #######################################################################################################################

# Display the models summary.
model.summary()

# Return the constructed LRCN model.
return model


 # Construct the required LRCN model.
 LRCN_model = create_LRCN_model()

 tm = TrainModel()
 tm.run(LRCN_model)
```

- When I tried printing the signatures, found empty.
  Please do help me with fixing the signature key issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the LSTM layer into its layer.LSTM.

It is mathematics when using linear Fn with LSTM you may need learning time but you may apply for scalars Fn or other Fns as well.

LSTM only also working but small paces and hundreds of steps are required you may apply for it classifications fns.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 32
IMAGE_WIDTH = 32
CHANNELS = 4

list_label_actual = [ 'Candidt Kibt', 'Pikaploy' ]

saved_model_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\DekDee naja"
saved_model_dir = os.path.dirname(saved_model_path)

print( saved_model_dir )

if not exists(saved_model_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(saved_model_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + saved_model_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=return_sequences, return_state=return_state )
        self.num_units = units
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences
        self.return_state = return_state

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
    
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Dataset
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 7.xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0])

list_label = [ ]
list_Image = [ ]
list_file_actual = [ ]

for Index, Image, Label in variables.values:
    print( Label )
    list_label.append( Label )
    
    image = tf.io.read_file( Image )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_Image.append(image)


list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.int32 )
list_label = tf.constant( list_label, shape=( 33, 1, 1 ) )
list_Image = tf.cast( list_Image, dtype=tf.int32 )
list_Image = tf.constant( list_Image, shape=( 33, 1, 32, 32, 4 ) )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( list_Image, list_label ))
list_Image = tf.constant( list_Image, shape=( 33, 32, 32, 4 ) ).numpy()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 ), name="input_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2., name="normal_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6., name="normal_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((32 * 32, 4), name="reshape_01"),
    MyLSTMLayer(96, False, False),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flattern_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu', name="dense_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, name="dense_03"),
])


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.000000001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.997, epsilon=1e-09,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'] )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.97 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=5000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Save
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.save(
    saved_model_dir,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None,
    save_traces=True
)

## Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model( saved_model_dir )
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open( saved_model_dir + '\\model.tflite', 'wb' ) as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
    
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_Image)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        tf.constant( list_Image[i], shape=( 32, 32, 4 ) ),
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```